# Properties to Database Columns (C#, EF Core)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework-core

I have programmed a TicTacToe game in WPF, which works perfectly fine.
Now, my task is to create a database which saves information about the gam each round it's been played.

=> so the database columns should look like this

*GameScoreId || Player X || Player O || GameMode || Winner || Loser || Game Status*

My GameScore Class looks like this:

```
public class GameScores
{
    private MainWindowViewModel? MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    private TicTacToeLogic? Game => MainWindowViewModel!.CurrentGame;
    public int? GameScoreId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerX => Game!.PlayerX.Name;
    public string PlayerO => Game!.PlayerO.Name;
    public Enum Mode
    {
        get
        {
            var mode = Game!.PlayerO switch
            {
                HumanPlayer => GameMode.HumanVsHuman,
                EasyCom => GameMode.HumanVsEasyBot,
                HardCom => GameMode.HumanVsHardBot,
                _ => throw new NotImplementedException(),
            };
            return mode;
        }
    }
    public string? Winner
    {
        get
        {
            if (Game!.GameOver && Game.GetFreeFields().Count is not 0)
                return Game.CurrentPlayer!.Name;

            return null;
        }
    }
    public string? Loser
    {
        get
        {
            if (Game!.GameOver && Game.GetFreeFields().Count is not 0)
                return Game.CurrentPlayer!.Enemy!.Name;

            return null;
        }
    }
    public Enum Status
    {
        get
        {
            if (Game!.GameOver && Game.GetFreeFields().Count is not 0)
            {
                return GameStatus.Win;
            }
            return GameStatus.Draw;
        }
    }
}
```

and my Context Class looks like this:

```
public class GameScoresContext : DbContext
{
    // table with gamescores
    public DbSet<GameScores>? GameScores { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=GameScoresDB;Integrated Security=True");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameScores>().HasKey(e => e.GameScoreId);
    }
}
```

}

After adding migration and updating the database on the NuGet Packet Manager Console, it creates a table on my Server which looks like this:
[image]

Why aren't the properties (GameScores class) being added as columns to the database? Or how can I add the properties as columns to my database?

Cheers!

Comment: Your dbContect need a property for each column of the database.  There is also an edmx file that maps the c# classes to the database tables and database columns.  The best way of fixing is to manually create the tables columns in the database and then refresh the mapping which will automatically update the classes in c#.

Comment: Add Setters to properties.

Comment: Is this a database-first setting? Decorate the class with `[Table]` and the properties with `[Column]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the properties need to be mapped as well

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameScores>().HasKey(e => e.GameScoreId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameScores>().Property(e => e.PlayerX);
    ...
}
```